# NSNumber responds positively to mutableCopy?

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, mutability

Is this a bug or is there a subtle lesson here?

```
NSNumber *someNumber = @(1);
[someNumber respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableCopy)]; // returns YES (!)
[someNumber respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableCopyWithZone:)]; // returns NO
```

Apple LLVM 7.1 (iOS SDK 9.3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `NSObject` itself implements `-mutableCopy` (for all objects, even those which do not conform to `NSCopying` or `NSMutableCopying`) by calling into `-mutableCopyWithZone:` (so that things implementing `NSMutableCopying` get to just implement `-mutableCopyWithZone:` without needing to repeat the implementation for `-mutableCopy`).

Everything that inherits from `NSObject` responds to `-mutableCopy`, but if you actually called it, it would crash because `NSNumber` doesn't respond to `-mutableCopyWithZone:`.

You can see this with

```
assert([NSObject instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(mutableCopy)] == [NSNumber instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(mutableCopy)])
```

bbum's analysis summarizes this pretty well — there are some subtle edge cases when doing these checks dynamically, because you may get answers you don't at all expect.

Comment: Thanks for the specifics on where it came from!

Comment: Great info. And if I had looked at the docs for NSObject: `This is a convenience method for classes that adopt the NSMutableCopying protocol. An exception is raised if there is no implementation for mutableCopyWithZone:.`

Comment: @BenFlynn Haha, I only half remembered this myself. This isn't exactly an easily discoverable feature, in code or documentation.

Answer (score 4):

That's odd.  I wouldn't expect the class to implement `-mutableCopy`.   May be fallout from the tagged pointer implementation (if so, then @(REALLYBIGNUMBERTHATISNEARMAX) would change the behavior).

The subtle lesson is that you can't really use `respondsToSelector:` for generic functionality tests.   Nor can you use `isKindOfClass:`.  There are many situations where it would fail (`NSArray` vs. `NSMutableArray` used to behave very strange-- may still-- when trying to use introspection to determine mutability, for example).

Introspection works well for explicitly declared situations like delegation or data sources.   Places where there is an `@protocol` declaration that specifically defines some set of `@optional` methods.